# Can I still get Shadow Links without Streetpass?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

I just started playing *The Legend of Zelda: A Link Between World* and found the guy talking about StreetPass and fighting Shadow Links. problem is that where i live i get next to no hits on StreetPass even when i left my 3DS on while going to work both in the game i was playing at the time and in *StreetPass Mii Plaza*

I saw there are a bunch of challenges and wouldn't mind aiming to clear them too but i assume i need to fight Shadow Links to be able to do them, in which case, can I still get Shadow Links without Streetpass? or can you only ever get them from StreetPass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From memory yes, you can find Shadow links without streetpass.

There's a couple of them directly inside the game that you can find on specific spots.

> Occasionally, a Shadow Link will appear without being met by StreetPass. This occurs once every few hours of gameplay, as long as Link has visited the StreetPass Tree at least once. These Shadow Links come from a supposed Player named Shade and are selected at random from the following list of 20 pre-generated characters, coming in a variety of bounties and item selections.

You can find a list on this wiki [here](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Link_Battle#Pre-Generated_Shadow_Links)